# How to force not yet ready Pod being deployed when Rolling Update schedules a new pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Deployment with one Pod `A`. I'm updating the deployment, let's say adding ENV variable to a container. It creates a new Pod `B` and waits for it to be ready.

However, before the new Pod `B` is ready, I'm updating the ENV again. That cancels the `B` and starts pod `C`.

Is there a way to allow Pod `B` to finish and whenever it's ready, it replaces `A`, and after `C` is ready, `C` replaces `B`?

In other words, I'd like `A` -> `C` (`B` terminated) to become `A` -> `B` -> `C`, no matter `C` is scheduled before `B` is ready.

By ready I mean ReadinessProbe.

Comment: That behavior matches what's described in [Rollover (aka multiple updates in-flight)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rollover-aka-multiple-updates-in-flight) in the Deployment documentation; that doesn't describe any way to change that behavior.